# Update TableView after adding CoreData

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

I'm working on a CoreData App which displays the content of the CoreData in a TableView.
The Problem is, after adding a string the tableView is not Updating the Content of the CoreData.

i tried it with:

```
    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)none
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

But no Chance, its not reloading.

Any guesses or should I post some more Code? thank you :)

So more Code :)

Saving string to CoreData:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate =
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context =
    [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    NSManagedObject *newProduct;
    newProduct = [NSEntityDescription
                  insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Products"
                  inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newProduct setValue: _textField.text forKey:@"productName"];
    NSError *error;
    [context save:&error];
    NSLog(@"Product saved");
}
```

And the Code of the TableViewController:

```
@implementation CartViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //Core Data Versuche


    /*
     Fetch existing events.
     Create a fetch request for the Event entity; add a sort descriptor; then execute the fetch.
     */
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Products"];
    [request setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Order the events by creation date, most recent first.
    // NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:NO];
    // NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];
    // [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Execute the fetch.
    NSError *error;
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSArray *fetchResult = [delegate.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (fetchResult== nil) {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }

    // Set self's events array to a mutable copy of the fetch results.
    [self setCartProductsArray:[fetchResult mutableCopy]];

    /*
     Reload the table view if the locale changes -- look at APLEventTableViewCell.m to see how the table view cells are redisplayed.
     */
    __weak UITableViewController *cell = self;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:NSCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {

        [cell.tableView reloadData];
    }];

    // Ende Core Data Versuche
}
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)none
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: The table doesn't update core-data. You update core-data and then update the table reflect the new data.

Comment: Yes, post more code. Both how you're trying to update Core Data and how you populate the table cells.

Comment: Shouldn't need `[self.tableView reloadData];` in `viewWillAppear`. But all you need to do now is update if the `fetchResult` changes, hence `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Comment: It seems that you used the code from my answer to your previous question. May I ask why you deleted the question after acknowledging that the answer helped?

Answer (score 2):

What you probably want to do is use an `NSFetchedResultsController`.

1. Make sure that when you are updating the data, you are really just updating CoreData.
2. When things change in CoreData and you have an `NSFetchedResultsController` you can subscribe to updates. Apple has great [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) on how to make this work. These updates will update your table correctly using the [delegation methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate). This ends up mostly being a copy and paste from the documentation.

Comment: The fetched results controller has its own sets of delegate methods that need to be implemented. it is not a simple [tableview reloadData]

Comment: Right, and it will make the app more efficient that way. If you want a simple `reloadData` you can still use it, just do reload the table in `controllerDidChangeContent:` (that would be the only method you implement). The being thing is getting a notification when data changes.

Comment: So i don't know if i got this right:
i Tried:
- (void) controllerDidChangeContent: (NSFetchedResultsController *) controller
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

Comment: Have you actually created an FRC? Have you hooked up a delegate? Have you connected the FRC to the tableview?